# How might one determine if bacteria are nitrogen fixing or not?

Tags: metabolism, bacteriology

If you had an isolate bacteria sample how would you determine if they were nitrogen fixing?

Comment: Would stable isotope probing be useful?

Comment: @zenbomb more of a comment than an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind found the answer myself you can use the [acetylene reduction assay](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC223907/).

Comment: as a quick screen, often nitrogen fixing bacteria die or stop fixing nitrogen when exposed to oxygen.

Comment: This is true, nitrogenase has a very low half life in the presence of oxygen- around 30 seconds. Never thought of that could be useful for further lab testing... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing a bioinformatic search of the bacterial genomes first before doing the experiments. You should be able to find homologues of the "nif" (nitrogen fixation) genes there.

Comment: Not ideal if you have no idea what the colony is at all though.